# store dictionary into userdefault as single array - Alamofire - SwiftyJSon

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, alamofire, swifty-json

```
{
  "message" : "success ",
  "status" : "1",
  "Result" : {
    "name" : "abc",
    "lastname" : null,
    "middlename" : null,
    "id" : 20431
  }
}
```

i want to store result object into single userdefaults using model and how to retrieve it

Comment: Please show us what you have tried.

Answer (score 1):

From the docs [here](https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON#raw-object). Have you tried like this:

```
//convert the JSON to a raw String
if let rawString = json.rawString() {
    userDefaults.set(rawString, forKey: "jsonData")
} else {
    print("json.rawString is nil")
}
```

Comment: how can i get this data via model?

Answer (score 0):

First create a model for this, using `Codable` protocol

```
struct MyJSON : Codable {
    let message : String?
    let status : String?
    let result : JSONResult? // Don't use Result, a keyword in swift 
}

struct JSONResult : Codable {
    let name : String?
    let lastname : String?
    let middlename : String?
    let id : Int?
}
```

Then Use the protocol to map the JSON, save the model in UserDefaults.

```
let jsonString = 

"""
{
  "message" : "success ",
  "status" : "1",
  "result" : {
    "name" : "abc",
    "lastname" : null,
    "middlename" : null,
    "id" : 20431
}
}
"""


let jsonData = Data(jsonString.utf8)
let data = try JSONDecoder().decode(MyJSON.self, from: jsonData)


// save model in userDefaults 
func saveModel() {
    if let encoded = try? JSONEncoder().encode(data) {
    UserDefaults.standard.set(encoded, forKey: "MySavedValue")
   }

}


//get the model 

func getModel() -> MyJSON? {
     guard let data = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "MySavedValue") as? Data else {
            return nil
        }
     return try? JSONDecoder().decode(MyJSON.self, from: data) 
}
```

how to use

```
saveModel()

print(getModel()?.message) // print("Success")
```